# Log4j DailyRollingFileAppender concurrency with multiple processes

Tags: java, concurrency, log4j

I have a number of identical processes that are writing to a single log file using a Log4j `DailyRollingFileAppender`. I am concerned that multiple processes may try and roll the file and that chaos will ensue. Does the implementation allow for this using with some kind of locking mechanism? - the [Javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) doesn't mention it.

Comment: Out of interest why not use separate log files, if it because you want an aggregated view then have you heard of Splunk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Log4j Logging to a Shared Log File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/log4j-logging-to-a-shared-log-file)

Answer (score 2):

it is not advisible to let multiple processes access the same log file. mayhem will occur