# DailyRollingFileAppender, losing previous day's data

Tags: java, log4j

**Day 1** Program start and works all day. Log is written as expected

**Day 2** Past midnight when first activity for the day happens (a cron in
my case) THAT ACTIVITY is recorded and all data for the Day 1 is lost.
This activity is recorded as Day 1 activity

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, R

log4j.appender.R = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File = ../log/ooo.log
log4j.appender.R.Append = true
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
```

**Example:**

In a `ooo.log.2011-10-20` i expect to find activity for 10-20
Instead i see first few seconds of 10-21

I expect behavior , as defined by the [specification](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html)

> '.'yyyy-MM-dd Rollover at midnight each day.  At midnight, on March
>   8th, 2002, /foo/bar.log will be copied to /foo/bar.log.2002-03-08.
>   Logging for the 9th day of March will be output to /foo/bar.log until
>   it is rolled over the next day.

Additionally, take a look at the timestamps. It appears to be random is consistent with the minute mark when my cron is called. Regardless of what it does though, appender's behavior is not consistent with its' description.

[image]

What's going on here? Please help me understand and correct.

Comment: What does your cron do? Does it run the Java program that is doing the logging (a `main()`-based app), or does it call a Java webapp that is doing the logging?

Comment: @SingleShot. Right on the money. It calls a class that contains it's own main(). But nothing weird is happening there, normal logging

Comment: The reason I ask is I suspect the rolling may only work for a continuously running app. At least, I would investigate that...

Comment: If upon main call, new JVM is started ... DailyRollingFileAppender belongs to some instance of JVM .. hmm ... but in that case wouldn't it be reasonable to expect log reset on the hour? In reality, it happens once a day

Comment: Also, from the Javadoc, "DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization issues and data loss. The log4j extras companion includes alternatives..." If possible, you may want to "upgrade" to LogBack which is a much nicer implementation (by the developer that created Log4J).

Comment: @SingleShot, please respond in a form of an "answer" so i can "accept it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may also be a symptom of multiple instances of a program logging to the same file; see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500212/log4j-dailyrollingfileappender-file-issues/7501270#7501270) and in other answers.

> Additionally, take a look at the timestamps. It appears to be random is consistent with the minute mark when my cron is called. Regardless of what it does though, appender's behavior is not consistent with its' description.

True. Rollover does not happen "on the hour", but with the first logged statement AFTER the rollover time mark (hence your file timestamps). And there is **no check** if the name of the file to which the rolled over part needs to be renamed is free to use.